# Where to store custom DLL files on Windows?

Tags: windows, dll

we need to deploy some custom DLL on Win7 Desktop computers that will be used for VBA.

Now, what would be the best location to store these files ?
Surely not in the standard Win locations such as Program Files or SystemXX folders...

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on a project which uses custom dlls and I place them in the workspace folder or the folder I am working from.

I use python(ctypes) so I have included them in the package that I am creating.

You can add the path of your dll location to the path variable as well if you like